# How is the destination MAC address automatically updated when the destination IP address is geven for an UDP frame in C#

Tags: c#, udp, ethernet

I have tried a program shown below:-

```
 class Program
{
    static IPEndPoint Mypoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.169.20.30"), 8050);
    static IPEndPoint UrPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.169.20.15"), 8051);
    static UdpClient TxClient;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        byte[] data= new byte[1472];
        TxClient = new UdpClient(Mypoint);
        while (i < 500)
        {
            data[i]++;
            try
            {
                TxClient.Send(data, data.Length, UrPoint);
            }
            catch { }
            Console.WriteLine("Sent frame " + ++i + " times\n");

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In this I am sending a series of frames to system with IP address 10.169.20.15. I am not giving any MAC ID for this system. 
But when I view the transmission of the frames through wireshark, I find that the destination MAC Id is automatically getting updated to the MAC Id of that system.

Could anyone please let me know how this is happening. Does the System automatically find out the MAC id corresponding to the IP address, or is there some other reason.

The reason I am asking this is because, I need to now communicate to a micro controller in UDP protocol. As I cannot update the destination MAC address in C#, will it be enough if I give just the IP address. Will the MAC Id be automatically resolved?

Hope the question is clear and thanks for your help !!!

Edit:- 
I tried using arp -s ipaddress mac address in command prompt and then running my program, but still the frame being sent is not being transmitted to the given mac address.

Could anyone please let me know how to resolve this. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, IP doesn't care about MAC addresses, ethernet software/drivers do.

The IP layer and above (which include TCP/UDP), is totally independent from the lower layers. It doesn't even know that ethernet is below, and it shouldn't (maybe it's not ethernet ?). The software for IP just build its packets and send them to the layer just below, and it doesn't matter what this layer is. This means there is no concept of MAC address on the IP level, and it's a good thing, it allows running IP on network with no MAC address.

Now, how is this MAC address updated  to the correct one as you observed ? This is actually very simple. Each device on the network knows the next one towards the packet destination, and just fills the MAC source and destination accordingly. Each device relays the packet on the ethernet network by filling correct MAC address.

Comment: @ ElderBug, does that mean that if I connect a microcontroller to the ethernet port in my pc, its MAC address will automatically be saved by the driver? and every time I send a frame to its IP address, the MAC is automatically updated?

Comment: @Bas The microcontroller MAC address will be stored on the PC in the ARP table. It's a table that is used to know to which device (MAC address) is associated with which IP. ARP is often seen as a layer between ethernet and IP. It's a bit like DNS (which IP is "google.com") but for lower layers. When the PC sends a packet, at some point a driver will look into the ARP table, and determine to which MAC it must sends the packet. The microcontroller will do the same on its side.

Comment: @Bas On windows and linux, you can use the `arp -a` command to display the ARP table (same command for both OS).

Comment: hello @ ElderBug, I tried using arp -s in command prompt and updating the IPaddress with the corresponding MAC id. but still the frame is not being transmitted to the required MAC id. It is just being transmitted to a default MAC of the router

Comment: @Bas If `arp -s` didn't do anything, you probably did it wrong. Anyway, since your MCU and your computer are connected to a router, the expected behavior is to use the MAC of the router. It won't work otherwise. In other words, packet being sent to the router MAC is normal. Also, you should not have to do anything on MAC and ARP level. If it doesn't work as is, the problem is probably not on MAC nor ARP.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. Now by connecting the MCU directly to the ethernet port of the PC, I am able to transmit by just modifying the arp table

Comment: @Bas You really shouldn't need to use `arp -s`. Does your MCU software have ARP enabled ? Any MCU with ethernet and IP stack should implement ARP. I mean, if it doesn't work as is, there IS a problem, and using `arp -s` is not a solution, only a workaround. You may choose to ignore the problem, but that's not really recommended. That stays true for direct link and router link.